# how to get the property from an object?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

please help bring in the template property of the object.

usually for a set of objects I deduce properties of the loop through the "FOR":

```
{% for entrie in news_all %}
    <br /><strong>{{ entrie.title }}</strong>
{% endfor %}
```

but now I passed to the template is only one object, so no need to use a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the object field using [dot notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups): `{{ entrie.title }}`

(assuming `entrie` is passed in the template context).

Though, if you are passing a queryset in the context, the result of `objects.filter()`, for example, that contains only one object, you can still use the dot notation: first get the first element from a `queryset`, then an attribute/field:

```
{{ entries.0.title }}
```

See some examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups).

Hope that helps.